# "disagrees about version of symbol" after changing struct spi_device

Tags: linux, kernel, spi

I am studying SPI device driver using my RPi4. I added a member variable in `struct spi_device` in *spi.h* to see if the variable I added in DTS (Device Tree source) comes in *spi.c* as intended:

```c
struct spi_device {
struct device dev;
struct spi_controller *controller;
struct spi_controller *master;
u32 max_speed_hz;
u32 debug_sheld; // ------> for testing..
// ....}
```

Then I compiled the kernel to see what happens in *spi.c* and *spidev.c* like this, rebooted my RPi4, and tried to load *spidev.ko* module. But, this error happens:

```sh
$ sudo insmod spidev.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module spidev.ko: Invalid parameters
```

I checked kernel log using `dmesg`:

```
[ 81.717199] spidev: disagrees about version of symbol spi_sync
[ 81.717211] spidev: Unknown symbol spi_sync (err -22)
[ 81.717248] spidev: disagrees about version of symbol spi_setup
[ 81.717257] spidev: Unknown symbol spi_setup (err -22)
[ 81.717278] spidev: disagrees about version of symbol __spi_register_driver
[ 81.717287] spidev: Unknown symbol __spi_register_driver (err -22)
[ 81.717311] spidev: disagrees about version of symbol spi_slave_abort
[ 81.717320] spidev: Unknown symbol spi_slave_abort (err -22)
[ 310.352225] spidev: disagrees about version of symbol spi_sync
[ 310.352237] spidev: Unknown symbol spi_sync (err -22)
[ 310.352274] spidev: disagrees about version of symbol spi_setup
[ 310.352283] spidev: Unknown symbol spi_setup (err -22)
[ 310.352305] spidev: disagrees about version of symbol __spi_register_driver
[ 310.352314] spidev: Unknown symbol __spi_register_driver (err -22)
[ 310.352338] spidev: disagrees about version of symbol spi_slave_abort
[ 310.352347] spidev: Unknown symbol spi_slave_abort (err -22)
[ 649.449228] spidev: disagrees about version of symbol spi_sync
[ 649.449244] spidev: Unknown symbol spi_sync (err -22)
[ 649.449291] spidev: disagrees about version of symbol spi_setup
[ 649.449303] spidev: Unknown symbol spi_setup (err -22)
[ 649.449332] spidev: disagrees about version of symbol __spi_register_driver
[ 649.449343] spidev: Unknown symbol __spi_register_driver (err -22)
[ 649.449375] spidev: disagrees about version of symbol spi_slave_abort
[ 649.449386] spidev: Unknown symbol spi_slave_abort (err -22)
```

There hasn't been any problem when I change something in *spi.c* or *spidev.c*, but I don't know why it happens with a modification to `struct spi_device`. Can somebody help me to solve this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Your driver calls `spi_sync`, `spi_setup` and other functions. And you expect that functions to work with **new** `spi_device` structure, with additional field.

But these functions are **already compiled**, and work with **old** `spi_device` structure (without additional field).

This is what the "disagrees about version of symbol" message means: most likely, calling these functions from your code won't work **correctly**.

You need either to recompile these functions (that is, rebuild the kernel), or leave `spi_device` structure unmodified and instead of additional field use some other ways for store additional info.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  According to your comment, I explicitly deleted spi.o, spidev.ko, and spidev.mod.* files and compiled the kernel again in the hope that they are re-linked with my struct spi_device modified. But the problem remains the same. I understand what you mean, but this seems to be a different matter. And, as you know, once content in header files is changed, source codes are recompiled (or re-linked) and that's why I didn't deleted those files above when I previously compiled the kernel with struct spi_device modified.  Would there be something that I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: You have recompiled the kernel and have **loaded** it (booted from it), haven't you? `insmod` inserts the module into the currently loaded kernel. What output of `uname -r` is?

Comment: Correct. After recompiling the kernel I tried to load spidev.ko by using insmod. Kernel version appears the same as 5.4.59-v7l+ regardless of the modification to struct spi_device.